# Filter one DataFrame by unique values in another DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, filtering, grouping

I have 2 Python Dataframes:

The first Dataframe contains all data imported to the DataFrame, which consists of "prodcode", "sentiment", "summaryText", "reviewText",etc. of all initial Review Data.

```
DFF = DFF[['prodcode', 'summaryText', 'reviewText', 'overall', 'reviewerID', 'reviewerName', 'helpful','reviewTime', 'unixReviewTime', 'sentiment','textLength']]
```

which produces:

```
     prodcode                                 summaryText                                         reviewText  overall      reviewerID    ...       helpful   reviewTime unixReviewTime  sentiment textLength
0  B00002243X  Work Well - Should Have Bought Longer Ones  I needed a set of jumper cables for my new car...      5.0  A3F73SC1LY51OO    ...        [4, 4]  08 17, 2011     1313539200          2        516
1  B00002243X                            Okay long cables  These long cables work fine for my truck, but ...      4.0  A20S66SKYXULG2    ...        [1, 1]   09 4, 2011     1315094400          2        265
2  B00002243X                  Looks and feels heavy Duty  Can't comment much on these since they have no...      5.0  A2I8LFSN2IS5EO    ...        [0, 0]  07 25, 2013     1374710400          2       1142
3  B00002243X       Excellent choice for Jumper Cables!!!  I absolutley love Amazon!!!  For the price of ...      5.0  A3GT2EWQSO45ZG    ...      [19, 19]  12 21, 2010     1292889600          2       4739
4  B00002243X      Excellent, High Quality Starter Cables  I purchased the 12' feet long cable set and th...      5.0  A3ESWJPAVRPWB4    ...        [0, 0]   07 4, 2012     1341360000          2        415
```

The second Dataframe is a grouping of all prodcodes and the ratio of sentiment score / all reviews made for that product.  It is the ratio for that review score over all reviews scores made, for that particular product.

```
df1 = (
    DFF.groupby(["prodcode", "sentiment"]).count()
    .join(DFF.groupby("prodcode").count(), "prodcode", rsuffix="_r"))[['reviewText', 'reviewText_r']]

df1['result'] = df1['reviewText']/df1['reviewText_r']
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1 = df1.pivot("prodcode", 'sentiment', 'result').fillna(0)
df1 = round(df1 * 100)
df1.astype('int')

sorted_df2 = df1.sort_values(['0', '1', '2'], ascending=False)
```

which produces the following DF:

```
sentiment      0     1     2
prodcode                        
B0024E6QOO  80.0   0.0  20.0
B000GPV2QA  67.0  17.0  17.0
B0067DNSUI  67.0   0.0  33.0
B00192JH4S  62.0  12.0  25.0
B0087FSA0C  60.0  20.0  20.0
B0002KM5L0  60.0   0.0  40.0
B000DZBP60  60.0   0.0  40.0
B000PJCBOE  60.0   0.0  40.0
B0033A5PPO  57.0  29.0  14.0
B003POL69C  57.0  14.0  29.0
B0002Z9L8K  56.0  31.0  12.0
```

What I am now trying to do filter my first dataframe in two ways.  The first, by the results of the second dataframe.  By that, I mean I want the first dataframe to be filtered by the prodcode's from the second dataframe where df1.sentiment['0'] > 40.  From that list, I want to filter the first dataframe by those rows where 'sentiment' from the first dataframe = 0.

At a high level, I am trying to obtain the prodcode, summaryText and reviewText in the first dataframe for Products that had high ratios in lower sentiment scores, and whose sentiment is 0.

Comment: can you post a sample of your 2nd df ?

Comment: Hi @Datanovice, I have already posted it.  It is the DF that has values 'sentiment',  ' asin', '0', '1', '2'.  Are you asking for a sample of the first data frame?

Comment: yes, and your desired output, that's really helpful for others, usually questions are answered v.quickly for pandas when there is a sample input, code and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
DF3 = pd.merge(DFF, df1, left_on='prodcode', right_on='prodcode')
print(DF3.loc[(DF3['0'] > 50.0) & (DF3['2'] < 50.0) & (DF3['sentiment'].isin(['0']))].sort_values('0', ascending=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

assuming all the data you need is in df1 and no merges are needed.

```
m = list(DFF['prodcode'].loc[DFF['sentiment'] == 0] # create a list matching your criteria
df.loc[(df['0'] > 40) & (df['sentiment'].isin(m)] # filter according to your conditions
```

Comment: All of the data exists in DFF that I need.  I am trying to do 2 filters on DFF.  1:. I am trying to filter DFF by the specific results in df1, to only show prodcodes where (df1['0'] > 40).  And 2: Filter the results of that list where 'sentiment' == '0' in DFF.   I tried to add your solution but  I don't believe the syntax is correct.  I am getting a syntax error.  I added the ) to the first line, but still doesn't like the second.

Comment: Can you show us a few lines from DFF? Create a sample if you can't share

Comment: does the above code work btw? I edited to match your variables.

Comment: I have added a sample of the DFF data frame.  And no I still get an error on your solution.  KeyError: 'prodcode'.

Comment: Can you print DFF.columns and post to your answer? Also try the edited code above that should work also replace df with sorted_df2

Comment: DFF.columns = 'prodcode', 'summary', 'reviewText', 'overall', 'reviewerID',
       'reviewerName', 'helpful', 'reviewTime', 'unixReviewTime', 'sentiment',
       'textLength'].

Comment: what is the name of the prodcode column in the new df? is it not sentiment ?